# How to get value of some column of association table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

how can I get a weight of product through a Record model? As I know, possible to get all products of certain record but I cannot find out the way getting the weight of certain product.

[image]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :eatings
end

class Eating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :records
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eating
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class WeightedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What relationships should have Record and Product models with WeightedProduct so user will be able to get weight of certain product through one line User.first.eatings.first.records.first.products.first.weight?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're after this:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eating
  has_many :weighted_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weighted_products
end

class WeightedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Then `User.first.eatings.first.records.first.weighted_products.first.weight`

I think that should work but haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that each product has one weighted product, then in that case you should add

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :weighted_product
end


class WeightedProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
end
```

and

```
 class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eating
  has_many :products 
 end
```